# What does it mean when google.com is browser in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I don't have much traffic, but in my Browser report, under Audience in Google Analytics, most of my searches right now are coming from Google.com.

Does this mean it's actually coming from the google web crawler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably not Google.com - I'm pretty sure that the first character is a unicode character that happens to look like a "G". A lot of people have started to see this recently.

This seems to be a new kind of referral spam - when I copied the name from my own GA account and copied it to the address bar the browser translated it to "http://xn--oogle-wmc.com/" which redirected to an unavailable domain stuffed with spam keywords.

Ignore it or filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

where are you seeing this information?

Here's a screenshot from my GA account, showing Google / Organic

[Screenshot from my GA account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tOFe.png)